# getting error: JAVA_HOME not set for Hadoop in Cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, java-home

I am trying to set JAVA_HOME in env.sh in Hadoop. I am using Cygwin on Windows 7. I have edited the env.sh as:

```
export JAVA_HOME= "/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"
```

In environment variables I have set `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`.

And the path as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;c:\cygwin\bin;c:\cygwin\usr\sbin`.

But still I am getting these errors:

```
/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found

': not a valid identifierlibexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 9: export: 

`/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 41: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 46: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 52: $'\r': command not found


/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: $'\r': command not found


Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

When I am doing `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it is giving `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26`.
I have checked everything possible on this website, but still facing the problem.

Comment: shouldn;t this export JAVA_HOME= "/cygdrive/C/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"   be export JAVA_HOME= "/cygdrive/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"

Comment: @satya That dosenot make a difference.

Comment: try this then  export JAVA_HOME= "/cygdrive/'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26'"

Comment: I have already tried this. same error